# How to fix unsupported Java version for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio, but when I try to run it I get:

> Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_80-b15: Java 1.8 or later is required.

But when I checked the Java version it is:

> java version "1.8.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 2.2. Preview 1 error: "Please use JDK 8 or newer"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335214/android-studio-2-2-preview-1-error-please-use-jdk-8-or-newer)

Answer (score 6):

1.Open your project in Android Studio and select
`File > Settings (on macOS, Android Studio > Preferences`).

2.In the left pane, navigate to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`.

3.Under Gradle `JDK`, choose the right JDK option.
Click OK.

Comment: Note that sometimes there may be compatibility issues with the compiled SDK version, and changing the compiled SDK version may also solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

> Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_80-b15: Java 1.8 or later is required.

It seems like you also have outdated Java 7 installed on your system. Simply uninstall it completely if you do not really need it or at least update it to most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions, especially after updating Android Studio will change the default JDK to a higher version. So, If you are using an older version you have to make changes according to you.

Firstly, to change the using JDK in Android Studio (Overall not for specific projects) the answer of @Albert.Qing is perfect, and no need to repeat his steps

if the issue still exists so you have to change it in your specific project.

> Open your project
>
> Open `Project Structure`
>
> Select `SDK Location`
>
> You will see the following sentence: JDK Location was moved to `Gradle Setting` - Click on the setting
>
> Change the `Gradle JDK` to a suitable version

Comment: The sentence "JDK Location was moved to `Gradle Setting` is not showing up in Android Studio Hedgehog.