# Choosing JDK 11 in Android Studio gives error Please choose JDK 8 or newer

Tags: java, android-studio

i am using Android Studio 3.1.3 in Mac. I have installed JDK 11 in System.

When i am going to set JDK in android studio then it shows me error message.

```
Please choose JDK 8 or newer
```

[image]

Comment: Try checking the "Use embedded JDK" option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 2.2. Preview 1 error: "Please use JDK 8 or newer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335214/android-studio-2-2-preview-1-error-please-use-jdk-8-or-newer)

Comment: @temerpacific Actually i have two java installed in my system JDK 8 and 11 and when i am choosing "Use embedded JDk option" then its picking JDk 8. and i think its not an duplicate of above mention question because in above question the issue was a white space in path, but in my case there is not space in path.

Comment: Have you tried moving the older JDK from the folder and then using the checkbox?

Comment: none of those worked for me. Im using android studio 4.2 canary 15

Comment: As https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues states, "Starting with version 4.2, Android Studio now runs on JDK 11."

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/11.0.9%2B7/eec35ebefb3f4133bd045b891f05db94/jdk-11.0.9_osx-x64_bin.dmg) one works for me: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home`.
Set it on both

- Android Studio -> JDK Location
- In `~/.bash_profile` -> `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home` for macOS

  - Or in Windows Environment for Windows users.

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2
Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259, built on December 2, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174 x86_64
macOS 10.16